# How to post form data using Jesrey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Am new to jersey.Am trying to post two form data using jersey call.The following is my code,

```
public class Test {     

    private static String baseuri = "http://json/authenticate";


    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {        


        try {
            Client client = Client.create();    
            WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseuri);             

            MultivaluedMap<String, String> postBody = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
            postBody.add("X-Username", "admin");
            postBody.add("X-Password", "password");

            ClientResponse response =  webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
                            .post(ClientResponse.class, postBody);   


            // check response status code
            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }

            // display response
            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... ");
            System.out.println(output + "\n");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

While am trying to run this code , i get the following error

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 415.**

Please any one help me with this..Thanks.

Comment: From this client, you are setting the media type as `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE`. Have you specified any other Media Type as input in your service?

Comment: **10.4.16 415 Unsupported Media Type** - The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method. [HTTP/1.1:Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Comment: no i didnt specify..can you please tell me what i have to change in my code?

Comment: i changed media type as "APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE" but am getting the following error "com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.sun.jersey.core.util.MultivaluedMapImpl, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found"

Answer (score 1):

Using url encoded form type, we need to format the body in specific way. As state [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)

> The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by `=` and name/value pairs are separated from each other by `&`.

So basically, the data should be sent in the form `key1=value2&key2=value2`, and any special characters should be url encoded. In your case, there are no special characters so we don't need any encoding, just formatting. So you client request might look something more like

```
WebResource resource = client.resource(Main.BASE_URI).path("form");

String username = "user";
String password = "pass";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append("X-Username").append("=").append(username).append("&");
builder.append("X-Password").append("=").append(password);

ClientResponse response = resource
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
        .post(ClientResponse.class, builder.toString());

String msg = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(msg);

response.close();
```

On the server side, you need to make sure the resource accepts (`@Consumes`) `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED` type data also, and has `@FormParam` annotations to extract the values (we can also us a `MultivalueMap`, but for easier access, we can use the annotation`. So your resource class might look something like

```
@Path("/form")
public class FormResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response doForm(@FormParam("X-Username") String username,
                           @FormParam("X-Password") String password) {
        return Response.ok("Good job " + username + "!").build();
    }
}
```

This should work fine, given all your other infrastructure parts are working.

Note: If you *do* have any special characters you need to encode, you can simple make use of `java.net.URLEncoder` and use `encode(String part, String encType)`

Comment: i got this error APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: I don't know where you are using this, but it should be `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`

Comment: i have used like this in my client request ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE)
          .post(ClientResponse.class, builder.toString());

Comment: You can also simple use the String version is needed `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It's the same as using `MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`

Comment: but i got the error and even in server side also i got the same

Comment: You are posting an error about `APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED`. That has nothing to do with the code you are showing me

Comment: How were you using it in your originial code that you posted? Maybe you just need to import the `MediaType`. `import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67193/discussion-between-asthcg-and-peeskillet).